# Number of solutions of a linear equation of n variables

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

```
// A Dynamic programming based C++ program to find number of
// non-negative solutions for a given linear equation
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Returns counr of solutions for given rhs and coefficients
// coeff[0..n-1]
int countSol(int coeff[], int n, int rhs)
{
    // Create and initialize a table to store results of
    // subproblems
    int dp[rhs+1];
    memset(dp, 0, sizeof(dp));
    dp[0] = 1;

    // Fill table in bottom up manner
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
      for (int j=coeff[i]; j<=rhs; j++)
         dp[j] += dp[j-coeff[i]];

    return dp[rhs];
}

// Driver program
int main()
{
    int coeff[]  = {2, 2, 5};
    int rhs = 4;
    int n = sizeof(coeff)/sizeof(coeff[0]);
    cout << countSol(coeff, n, rhs);
    return 0;
}
```

I am new to competitive programming, I just stumbled upon this code. I would like to know the intuition behind this particular snippet, like how does the second `for` loop help. Thank you.

```
   // Fill table in bottom up manner
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
          for (int j=coeff[i]; j<=rhs; j++)
             dp[j] += dp[j-coeff[i]];
```

This is using a bottom up approach, and
Suppose if `j= 3` and `j-coeff[i] = 2`

so how does `d[3] = d[3] + d[2]` give the solution? How can a simple addition of a previous result and a current result give the total solution of linear variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that you have unlimited number of coins with value 2,3,5 (your `coeff[]`) and you want to know number of solutions to make some sum form give coin set.

At the first loop run you fill table with coins 2. Table will be filled

```
idx    0  1  2  3  4  5  6
num    1  0  1  0  1  0  1
```

because there is the only way to get even sum with such coins.

At the second loop run you fill table with coins 3 - now you'll have sums that might be composed from coins 2 and 3

```
idx    0  1  2  3  4  5  6
num    1  0  1  1  1  1  2
```

Note that cell 5 filled with 2+3 - similar to your question situation, and cell 6 now contains 2 variants: 2+2+2 and 3+3

Comment: I am sorry but I still feel so confused about this problem. I don't know how to change recursive approach to DP approach,

Comment: @Hoang Nam I described DP approach (bottom-up way). Recursion for such problems usually starts from the end (top-down way), it could be easily replaced with top-down DP - memoization, but transformation to bottom-up (table) way is a bit more complex.